# My "ACTION_MOVE" is never called inside my longPressListener

Tags: java, android

I want my ACTION_MOVE to track the user toutch  when the screen is longPressed.

But my issue is that my ACTION_MOVE is never called.On the other hand my ACTION_DOWN is succesfuly runned.

Does someone know how i can fix my problem ?
Thank you for youre help !

This is my code :

```
 onLongPressListener = new OnLongPressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    if(isPointTouched(e) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(100, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                          float x;
                          float y;
                        switch(e.getAction()){
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                x = e.getX();
                                y = e.getY();
                                Log.d("Action down", Float.toString(x));
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                x = e.getX();
                                y = e.getY();
                                Log.d("Action Move", Float.toString(x)); // i want this function to track the user movement
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }};
```

Comment: read [onLongPress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onLongPress(android.view.MotionEvent)) method documentation and what is `MotionEvent e` parameter passed to that method

Comment: Do you know how i can fix my issue ?

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? `onLongPress` is called once after long press delay - it is not called multiple times

Comment: I want the ACTION_MOVE method to be re-run in a loop as soon as the user moves his finger after a longPress. This will allow me to move a drawing that is located in my view

Comment: tried to override `OnGestureListener#onScroll` method?

Comment: No, how i can achieve that ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#detect

Comment: and? do you know how `GestureDetecor`s work now?

Comment: Yes, but finally i came with just the onTouch for tracking the user finger

Comment: you dont have to use any `onTouch` - you have `onScroll` method for that

Comment: Okay i will use it ^^

Comment: additional advantage: you have `float distanceX, float distanceY` delta x and y parameters passed to `onScroll` method

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `OnLongPressListener` is your custom interface.
There is `View.OnLongClickListener` but it fires once the long click is performed. 
The long click is the event which is fired when the user holds his finger on the UI component for a long duration of time (hundreds of millis). It is fired once and if the user continue to hold the finger no extra event will appear.

To reach your purpose you should implement `GestureDetector` `OnGestureListener` to not only handle events but also divide them on types (`OnGestureListener` will help with that)

Google provides simple tutorial how to work with that:
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector

Comment: I tried to implement OnGestureListener when the user keep clickng i get the same problem

Comment: Can you show the example of the code you implemented?